# Best way of storing/caching real-time data , with disk persistency

Tags: c++, caching, real-time, persistent-storage

I am on Windows, using Visual Studio 2010 C++.

My Application processes a lot of data every 16ms (near-realtime). This data is basically a binary buffer of electric signals.

I need to store this data somehow that would allow for fast access.

My preference is to store some of this data in memory as it comes in real-time , and then persist it to disk in some fashion.

My app could at any point require data from any part in the session (beginning to current), and so access needs to be fast, and it would be nice if the queries could be cached for a certain amount of time as well.

So basically if anyone has experience with storing/caching and retrieving real-time data, it would be very helpful.

Any Ideas?

Roey

Comment: take a look at redis: http://redis.io/

Comment: this is not an exact answer. Topic starter should have some mapping to store his objects into redis. Anyway it's not worst option to save the data/

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the ORM tools -- object-relational mapping. In short -- tools to keep your objects in SQL DB. Another way is to use object storages. Google for them too.

There is a number of tools in both categories. You should chose one that fits best for you by its price, performance and ease of use.